# merging object with another based on the id and refer as new property for sorting

Tags: javascript

I have two bigger objects, for now just keeping it simple to understand. i need to merge those two objects with required properties and sort it out.

First i need to merge two objects based on the product_id from one object key to the other object reference key.

Then i need to pick the one more object data from the second main object.

Once its done need to sort it, but seems like this takes more time

```js
const productsList = {
  27: {
    id: 2,
    limit: 4363614,
    initial_limit: '1',
    date: null,
  },
  59: {
    id: 13,
    limit: 757502,
    initial_limit: '1',
    date: null,
  },
  62: {
    id: 30,
    limit: 394878,
    initial_limit: '2',
    date: null,
  },
};

const updatingDataList = {
  updatedData: {
    '1INCHEQC': {
      open_value: 0.2834,
      high_value: 0.2954,
      prcing: 68357.32,
      volume: 237875,
      product_id: 59,
    },
    '2INCHEQF': {
      open_value: 82.79,
      high_value: 88.54,
      low: 81.99,
      prcing: 62054.321,
      volume: 739,
      product_id: 62,
    },
    '3INCHEQS': {
      open_value: 0.2806,
      high_value: 0.2975,
      prcing: 300550.43,
      volume: 1053694,
      product_id: 89,
    },
  },

  originalData: {
    59: '23.123',
    62: '3452.21',
    89: '456.11',
  },
};

// first need to merge this two based on the product_id
const productsListUpdatingDataListAndOriginalDataMergedObject = Object.keys(
  productsList
)?.reduce((result, productId) => {
  const matchingUpdatingData = Object.values(updatingDataList.updatedData)?.find(
    item => item.product_id === parseInt(productId, 10)
  );

  if (matchingUpdatingData) {
    // extract only the required props from the product list
    const { limit } = productsList[productId];

    result[productId] = {
      limit,
      updated_data: { ...matchingUpdatingData, originalData: updatingDataList.originalData[productId] },
    };
  }

  return result;
}, {});

const sortedData = Object.values(
  productsListUpdatingDataListAndOriginalDataMergedObject
)?.sort(
  (firstProduct, secondProduct) =>
    secondProduct.updated_data.originalData - firstProduct.updated_data.originalData
);

console.log(sortedData);
```

How to optimise the code any better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` call will slow things down when you have a large dataset. Instead of iterating `productsList` and looking up the matching product id in `updatingDataList`, do the opposite: iterate `updatingDataList` and look up the corresponding product id in `productsList`. That lookup can be done by key, contrary to your approach where you have to use `find`:

```js
const productsList = {27: {id: 2,limit: 4363614,initial_limit: '1',date: null,},59: {id: 13,limit: 757502,initial_limit: '1',date: null,},62: {id: 30,limit: 394878,initial_limit: '2',date: null,},};

const updatingDataList = {updatedData: {'1INCHEQC': {open_value: 0.2834,high_value: 0.2954,prcing: 68357.32,volume: 237875,product_id: 59,},'2INCHEQF': {open_value: 82.79,high_value: 88.54,low: 81.99,prcing: 62054.321,volume: 739,product_id: 62,},'3INCHEQS': {open_value: 0.2806,high_value: 0.2975,prcing: 300550.43,volume: 1053694,product_id: 89,},},originalData: {59: '23.123',62: '3452.21',89: '456.11',},};

const sortedData = Object
    .values(updatingDataList.updatedData)  
    .filter(item => productsList[item.product_id])
    .map(item => ({
        limit: productsList[item.product_id].limit,
        updated_data: {
            ...item,
            originalData: updatingDataList.originalData[item.product_id]
        }
    }))
    .sort((a, b) =>
        b.updated_data.originalData - a.updated_data.originalData
    );

console.log(sortedData);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, it seems like performance has been increased and slowness is literrally came to zero seconds. Thanks @trincot